# Hibernate search: How can I search with contain character

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

In the database I have 4 string following:  user, user1, user2,user4.
When I search with string is user, I will get only value is user, How can I get all value in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

1. If the difference between 2 different values is just the number after the name ('user1' and 'user2'), you can use the [LowerCaseTokenizerFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory) which drops non letters, so 'user1', 'user2' and 'user4' will be indexed 'user'.
2. You can use the [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) which creates n-grams from the field to index, so 'user4' will be indexed : 'u', 'us', 'use', 'user', 'user4'. In this case, you will find 'user', user1', 'user2' and 'user4' when your keyword is : 'u', 'us', 'use', or 'user'.
3. As @srs mentioned, you can use a wildcard query.

Comment: thank you so much. But What the way have best performance ? Using EdgeNGramFilterFactory or using wildcard query :-/

Comment: You're welcome :) I didn't compare their performance. EdgeNGramFilterFactory takes more time when indexing and needs more memory. While wildcard takes more time when fetching data and do not apply the analyzer on the matching terms. If you decide to use wildcard, don't put " * " or " ? " at the beginning of the keyword like (" *user ") if you have a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve the problem at *query time* you can create the query object with "**wildcard**" and search **"user*"** to get all results. Follow an example :

```
Query q = yourQueryBuilderInstance.keyword().wildcard().onField("yourField")
        .matching("user*").createQuery();
```